# Why props render as undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have this React-component called PersonCard:

```
class PersonCard extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
    this.state = props;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={Mui} >
                <Card>
                    <CardHeader
                    title={this.props.firstName}
                    />
                </Card>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonCard;
```

The view has multiple PersonCards and they're mapped from an array in its parent component SearchResults as follows:

```
class SearchResults extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          data: [],
        }
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('http://localhost:3005/persons')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
              data:responseJson
            })
          })
        }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {
              this.state.data.map( (person)=>
                <PersonCard key={person.id} personProp = {person} />
              )

            }
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

The logger in the constructor shows the person objects and their properties correctly, so it's there as it should be.

BUT the props value (this.props.firstName) doesn't show in the render-method, since they get rendered as "undefined" on the view. Why?

Comment: Not sure why you have them, but remove the curly braces in your render between your `div`

Comment: Also, don't do `this.state = props`. Not only is it anti-pattern to directly set props to state in the constructor, but you are also doing so incorrectly by assigning the reference of props to your state, not its values -- basically if you mutate your state you will also mutate your props, which is a big no-no.

Comment: @Chris `this.state = something` is allowed in constructor.

Comment: @Madhavan.V, yes, such as a new object, it is. But setting the props is discouraged. Also, `this.state = props` assigns the reference of props to state, not its values. The problem is two-fold here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't define a prop called `firstName` here:

```
<PersonCard key={person.id} personProp = {person} />
```

Maybe you meant to access it through `this.props.personProp.firstname`?

Comment: @Chris R is correct.  personProp will be passed down to PersonCard so firstName will be inside personProp.  If you dont want this you could do somethin like: `<PersonCard key={person.id} {...person} />`

Comment: actually {...person} solved it. I didn't know about this syntax at all. I thought the object will have all it's properties in it. Must be my Java bacground ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are pass "key" and "personProp" props to "PersonCard" components. So inside the render function of "PersonCard" component you can access these props by "this.pops.key" and "this.props.personProp".

So if your personProp contain's the firstName then you will be able to access it by "this.prps.personProp.firstName". So you should try below code

```
class PersonCard extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
  this.state = props;
}

render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={Mui} >
            <Card>
                <CardHeader
                title={this.props.personProp.firstName}
                />
            </Card>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
   );
  }
}

export default PersonCard;
```